# Condition variable in qt, where to declare

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have two qhreads, where one thread needs to wait for the other using a condition variable. The example of my case `QWaitCondition` is given [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html#details).

So I have a condition variable `QWaitCondition my_condition;`. This variable must be visible to both threads. My question is: where should I define `my_condition`? I don't like using global variables. However, should it be a global variable? If it needs to be global where should I put it's definition so it's visible to both threads?

Comment: You can pass it in thread constructor or initialization, declaring it outside in the class that creates threads.

Comment: @Jepessen Thanks! So I just pass it by reference?

Comment: Declare it as a pointer in both threads and define it wherever the threads live I would say (so yes, pass by reference :-) ). You also need to use mutex to ensure only one thread at a time modifies the value.

Comment: @Resurrection so I also need to pass a mutex to thread constructors?

Comment: Well, maybe not if both threads live in the same thread (i.e. main thread) but if they live in different threads you will need mutex to guard the variable. Note that the thread QThread lives in is NOT the thread it governs - which is often confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it anywhere. For instance, declaring it as a member variable of your main app QObject (such as your QMainWindow subclass if this is a GUI app), and passing a pointer to it to the constructor of the threaded QObjects accessing the condition variable, would work just fine.

It seems that you are confusing thread safety and variable scope. In your case, a thread is just a class that needs to access a variable (the QWaitCondition) via a pointer. Just pass this pointer to the class constructor and store it.

Comment: The problem is that instances of QWaitCondition and QMutex are non-copyable objects. Not sure if I can pass a pointer to a mutex to the constructor.

Comment: @Alex You're passing a pointer, not the pointed-to value. The pointer can be copied to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

Make common.h/gaobal.h file.

globle.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_h
#define GLOBAL_h

#include<QQueue>
#include<QMutex>
#include <QtGlobal>  // you must have to include.
#include <QWaitCondition> 


static QQueue <QString> The_Queue;
static QMutex m_mutex;
static QWaitCondition m_QueueEmpty;

#endif // GLOBAL_h
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "popmsg.h"
#include "pushmsg.h"
#include "global.h"   


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    popmsg m_pop;  //Thread 1
    pushmsg m_push;//Thread 2
    m_push.start();
    m_pop.start();
    m_push.wait();
    m_pop.wait();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here i have 2 thread and waitcondition, queue, mutex is global for both thread.